# How to remove this bug from my app .this error occur only in a few divices

Tags: android, failed-installation

[Error message in realme mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYOPN.jpg)

I used **AIDE** to code and build my app i'm a beginner here. i don't understand why this happens in some mobiles but works fine in other.

For example my app runs perfectly fine on a Samsung mobile but it keeps failing to start even MainActivity while i didn't used the DialogFragment class in that activity in a RealMe device . Any help would be appreciated regarding this. Thanks

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. please don't post your code as screenshots, all code should be posted in your question as text, this just helps everyone way more to help you debug. also please consider posting any other relevant code related to your issue, such as the code for that fragment listed in the logs. welcome :)

Comment: The error says  mydialogfragment must be a public static class . But AIDE says mydialog fragment can't be a public class because the java file name doesn't match wht to do now